# fb audience network not showing real ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network

when I try fb audience network test ads they work perfectly fine but when I place real ads they do not work.
another error that I get after activating native Fb ads my app shows pop and it says:

[ads error pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy0ad.jpg)

does anyone have face any similar issues?